How to decompose the metric tensor orthonormally?
In fact I don't know how to explain my question properly.So I would like to introduce the following condition.
[width=0.5,scale=0.5]
Now let's consider two questions.
1)When observer A want to do experiment, how know he his basis are $\{\tau_1,S_1\}$ or $\{\tau_1,S_1'\}$?
2)Suppose A choose the basis $\{\tau_1,S_1\}$ and B $\{\tau_2,S_2\}$, according to inertial frames can't be distinguished from each other, I think both A and B will think the metric tensor components in their basis would be $(-1,1)$(Now 1+1 spacetime), but this seems impossible, because like a vector, if its components in basis $\{e_i\}$ and in $\{f_i\}$ are the same, then the two basis should be the same!
Thank you for your answering!

How would you answer  the Euclidean geometry analogue of your question?

@robphy In fact I don't know.But if we don't require the two observers write down, say, (1,1) in their own basis vector, because we don't have the relativity principle. Then this would not be a problem.

I dont know why I get negative vote.In fact I found someone asked a very similar question {https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/87105}
But there is no satisfying answer...

I didn't down vote it, but I can offer a reason why it might be: I have no idea what you are talking about....the picture's critical marks are messy, the letter I has no dot, and then prime looks like a dot, why not use $x_j$ for the orthogonal vector (I said j because my browser autocapitalized I, I can't stand it).  The "t"'s look like $\tau$, which is proper time, not coordinate time. $s$ is usually an invariant interval, and now its $s'$ which is something else. Recap: sharp t's for coordinate time, $x$ for spatial directions, $s$ for invariant intervals, don't mix dots and primes.

Also: you are correct in saying you don't know how to explain question. Is (1) just: how does a frame pick it's "spatial axis", or a vector lying in it's hyper plane of simultenatey? In (2), I have problem with A and B sharing 1 and 2 subscripts: make the coordinate subscripts match the coordinates. I don't want to be mapping $A\rightarrow 1$, or $A\rightarrow '$...prime is special in SR meaning "a different frame". Tighten the question up and you'll get an answer.

Finally, fr fr: The final sentence on the figure is confusing because the comma and the conjunction. That introduces a new sentence: "$s_i$ is not...." is not what? The verb needs an object. If there is no comma, then it's a list and the "not orthogonal" is implied, or if it were to say "...are orthogonal, while $s_i$ is not"...that works. English has lots of weird subtleties like that. So it all adds up to: hard to read, hard to follow $\rightarrow$ hard to answer.

(For simplicity, we restrict to a 2-dimensional space,
which is (1+1)-dim in special relativity or Galilean relativity.)

1)When observer A want to do experiment, how know he his basis are
$\{\tau_1,S_1\}$ or  $\{\tau_1,S'_1\}$

In special relativity, one can do a radar experiment to find the set of events (a line, more generally a hyperplane) that is simultaneous according the inertial observer with 4-velocity $\hat\tau_1$.

Given an inertial worldline 4-velocity $\hat\tau_1$ and an event $O$ on that worldline, consider the events 1 tick before and after event $O$. Draw the future light-cone of the past event and the past light-cone of the future event.
The intersection events of those cones are simultaneous according this inertial observer. The 4-vector $\hat S_1$ is the spacelike vector from event $O$ to the intersection event in the forward spatial direction. In fact, this vector is a spatial vector (i.e. has zero time-component) according to $\hat\tau_1$... and is a spatial unit-vector. (Note given the above physically-based construction, there is no "choice"... other than maybe which is the forward spatial direction.)
Construct the future and past light-cones for the events 2 ticks before and after event $O$... then do it for the events 3 ticks before and after.



More generally, using the construction in my answer to the question you referenced in your comment ( Can we show that time is orthogonal to space? ) which gave you "no satisfying answer", one can construct the "unit circle" with center at event $O$ and construct the tangent to the "circle" where this "circle" intersects the worldline at $\hat \tau_1$ (the first tick after event $O$ on that worldline). That tangent line is parallel to the line-of-simultaneity constructed above. (The tangent-line to the circle-in-this-geometry is orthogonal-in-this-geometry to the radius to that circle-in-this-geometry.)



Another inertial observer with 4-velocity $\hat \tau_2$ would construct
a different vector $\hat S_2$ that is orthogonal-in-this-geometry to $\hat \tau_2$.

In Special Relativity, $\hat S_1$ and $\hat S_2$ are not parallel, although they are in Galilean relativity.

Each observer will construct a metric tensor of the form [in my $(+,-[,-,-])$-convention] $\left(\begin{array}{rr} +1 & 0\\0& -1\end{array}\right)$. NOTE: The metric tensor is not a 4-vector in spacetime.
(Its diagonal is not a 4-vector in spacetime.)

And, of course, each observer will determine that $\hat\tau_1 \cdot \hat S_1=0$ and $\hat\tau_2 \cdot \hat S_2=0$ and
$\hat\tau_1 \cdot \hat\tau_1=1$ and $\hat S_1 \cdot \hat S_1=-1$ and
$\hat\tau_2 \cdot \hat\tau_2=1$ and $\hat S_2 \cdot \hat S_2=-1$.
But generally, $\hat\tau_1\cdot \hat\tau_2\geq 1$ and $\hat\tau_1\cdot \hat S_2\neq 0$ and similarly for $\hat\tau_2$.



Finally I will answer this question myself. And the answer is physically very simple.
If A,B are two observers, then if they feel like the lab is inertial (this is possible by equivalence principle), then the frame is the Fermi coordiante system (up to a translation) and so the basis are orthogonal.
